# Javascript slice out file name extension from html5 embedded video

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html5-video

I'm trying to remove the file name extension .mp4 from the `"+ element +"` result only.
I have tried `imagesdata.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")` but it doesn't work or i'm doing it wrong.

```
function createImagesTag(data){
    var imagesdata = JSON.parse(data);
    images=imagesdata;
    var imagesTag="";
    var a=0;
    imagesdata.forEach(element => {
        if(a==0){
            imagesTag+="<video muted preload='metadata' width='80%' height='40%' id='images_"+a+"' onclick='changeSelected("+ a +")' class='imagescards' <source src='"+ element +"#t=0.5'type='video/mp4' style='border: 3px solid red;'></video><br />"
        }
        else{
            imagesTag+="<video muted preload='metadata' width='80%' height='40%' id='images_"+a+"' onclick='changeSelected("+ a +")' class='imagescards' <source src='"+ element +"' type='video/mp4'></video><br />"
        }
      a++;
    });

    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = imagesTag;

}
```

Comment: Since you are using `.foreach` on `imagesdata` then I guess `imagesdata` is an array. Maybe that is why `imagesdata.split(".")` is not working

Comment: Yes is an array, it will display multiple results do you have any idea on how can I archive my goal?

Comment: Use `element = element.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer @Carsten Løvbo Andersen this `element = element.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".")` fixed my problem.